# Force form to change with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

Can anyone tell me how to force a form change in jQuery. I am manually setting values with jQuery, but the form doesn't enter this function:

```
$('form[name="xy"] :input').change(function() { ...
```

Can I manually do this to enter this function?

Comment: Maybe like this?  `$('form[name="xy"] :input').change()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/):

```
$('form[name="xy"] input').trigger('change');
```

or `change` method:

```
$('form[name="xy"] input').change();
```

Answer (score 0):

Triggering a UI event, like change in this case may not be a good code practice, as events should generally be dispatched only by UA to notify App logic about changes in UI. You may consider re-organizing your code, so that it would become possible for you to invoke logic you want to call directly, not through a loop of dispatching pseudo-event.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts. I am trying to select an option like this: `$("select[name='inptAvailability'] option[value='" + selectedAvailability + "']").attr('selected', 'selected');` and in my opinion, this should trigger an event automatically, but it is not the case :(